# Magento 2: How use attributes options for the dropdown box?

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute, dropdown-attribute

I created a customer attribute. it is a dropdown box, I did create Options inside the attributes. It was use in customer profile page.

I have a checkout page, want to display this attributes dropdown box with all the options. It can call the user selected values.

Below is the XML for the dropdown box, what replacement I need to get the attributes option and generate the dropdown box?

```
<item name="checkout_industry" xsi:type="array">
   <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select</item>
   <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
       <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
       <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
       <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/select</item>
   </item>
       <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Please select value</item>
               <item name="value" xsi:type="string"></item>
           </item>
           <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Value 1</item>
               <item name="value" xsi:type="string">value_1</item>
           </item>
           <item name="2" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Value 2</item>
               <item name="value" xsi:type="string">value_2</item>
           </item>
       </item>
   <item name="value" xsi:type="string">value_2</item>                                                                                      
   <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
   <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.checkout_industry</item>
   <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Select Industry</item>
   <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">5</item>
```